# Activity under translucent Activity missing onSaveInstanceState call

Tags: android, android-activity

When my first activity overlaps by second translucent activity and then by another non-translucent activity - state of first activity is not saving on rotation. There is any hack to force saving state?

1. I have `activity` (A) which overlaps by another one (B) (translucent)
   [image]
2. Then i open non-translucent activity (C) and my `activity` (A) goes into state 'stopped' with calling `onSaveInstanceState`
   [image]
3. Then i close non-translucent activity and my `activity` (A) goes into state 'started' such as documentation says.
   [image]
4. Now after rotating device my `activity` (A) missing onSaveInstanceState call. More over, state of `fragments` and his `ViewModels` is not saved too.

There is any hack to force saving state of `activity` and `fragments` under `translucent` activity?

Comment: have you check onSaveInstanceState() not called.

Comment: Sure, it's not called. On third step onRestoreInstanceState is not called, perhaps therefore onSaveInstanceState not calling again on rotation.